# how much processes are build after running this code?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system

this program is running on Unix:

```
 main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
         forkthem(5)
    }
    void forkthem(int n)
    {
         if(n>0)
         {
             fork();
             forkthem(n-1);
         }
    }
```

we tried to build a tree of processes but we didn't really got an answer.
we will be very thankful if anyone help us.

Comment: you would do well to add dbg mesgs like `printf("%s %n\n", "Insider ver #", n)` and maybe `sleep(100)` so you can see the process tree. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When n=0, then one process, the original one.
When n=1, then one fork happens, so two processes
When n=2, then each of the two n=1 processes forks again, so 4 processes
...
When n=k,   2**k processes

So, n=5 means 32 processes